# Proving function is not onto

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Let A represent the set of real numbers other than $-1$. Consider $f: A \to  R$ defined by 
$f(a) =\frac{ 2a}{ a + 1}$

How would I prove this function is not onto?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $y = \dfrac{2a}{a+1}$, we obtain $2a = ay + y \implies a(2-y) = y \implies a =\dfrac{y}{2-y}$. Hence, $y=2$ is never hit by any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

For the $y=2 \in \Bbb R$, does there exist a point $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=2$?